# Factorize expression by specific term

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, algebra, factorization

I am new to Mathematica  but I would like to know how to force Mathematica to factorize an expression by a specific term.

Exemple, imagine I have a term like this:

[image]

And I have an expression like this:

[image]

I want Mathematica to factorize this expression by Gamma like that:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to get your result is to use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html.en)

```
Activate[Inactive[( s a)/(b c s)] /. b c -> s/γ]
```

[image]